# Traits or services for controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method and variable which i want to be used on multiple controllers. I'm not too sure whether to use traits or services as both of them to my understanding serve almost the same purpose?

```
private $app_id;
private $archiving;

public function setArchieve()
{
    $this->app_id = config('archiving.id');
    $this->archiving = Application::findOrFail($this->app_id);
}

public function guzzleClient() {
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->archiving->token,
    ];

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'headers' => $headers,
        'http_errors' => false,
        'base_uri' => $this->archiving->url . '/api/',
    ]);

    return $client;
}
```

Comment: Subjective. Either is as good as the other. If you are working alone, you be the boss on deciding what to use. If you are using traits, u just call/include it and that's it. If services you have to call individual methods.

Comment: so using traits we get all the methods but services we get only the ones we call ?

Comment: Generally yes, with service also you will be getting all the methods, but you will have to call them in the controller methods. With traits, its like a separate file that contains container methods. Check Laravel's Login controller for instance, it uses a trait called `  use AuthenticatesUsers;` all methods needed are there.

Comment: Also, this cehck this. Its the same question and got good replies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280730/using-traits-for-service-layer-is-it-bad-practice